# windows system tray icon as a service

Tags: python, windows, windows-services, wxpython, system-tray

I have created a python application that runs as a service and has a system tray icon (for Windows). I am using wxPython as the wrapper program that calls the main program as a thread. The problem is that when I start the program as a service, the main program runs but the system tray icon is not created.

I have read that creating a system tray icon as a Windows service is not ideal but again have found conflicting information on that topic.

Here is my code:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys,os,time

#// Wx
import wx.adv
import wx #pip install wxpython
from wx.lib.embeddedimage import PyEmbeddedImage
from threading import Thread
#from pubsub import pub #pip install PyPubSub

TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'test5' 
get_python_logo = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAATCAIAAAAvYqvDAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAACjUlE"
    "QVQokQXBW4/bRBgA0G++ufhux068abaQUvUmASovCHhC/HOe+oCQkFYVSKjbVQXsshuycXwb"
    "ezw3ziH+6idvUJuAh/VvVzd5eRnnZZSEd7efpDx+9/3bqbnjTlL0CGb2oAk6QmxepFkeE2LP"
    "5+N6U4QRs1NvnaKUEOoRqEXugWhtZLEKt0/K9ToLAnJRr7JEDGNjnSTcADUMGAWky2SHvmO8"
    "IkkS8OiCI01FnKVSdWnIgFBvFvSGg4+8j8bJAY3BBoApj9bgwizbeh8xkQGJnAtRQ+BJyKKc"
    "iixbbZ1DWKzSRC1OJOXiqYXAeO5pwJRDpeys7eSBRInUYLRarAGvs1SchplwSATEgrNOlvPs"
    "hgnPHb3Ylf0EljBPnLMRE+Gxib0TJuEkT5jsv3z1w4+Q1Nfv3lPyYplkulpruwBZ5DC//erZ"
    "k69fwPnhz19/YY4I1/QY7F5+8y3Eu+JlAMDAG6AWpkfABaax/fcxiHKG0c0fH2/Ebb17+gb6"
    "CnnqgRFOEJbT6bbM+afr983hr/3TLbu8hA8f/0Yzns+2H3FxQVHVSs9q7gJhtVqiqGvxfrNZ"
    "ITNtTOTr/Trmc5l4XJp1CqgbNx3rgk6nf54/r8vEE92wpW+dHP0sz3cd0NXcqhB8wvixeZxz"
    "1h4OMG5xnuSpYVm8qUI7n2ZhuHeiCmOxsIt4M4SV792zej89DIUoC5oysF5Q1Mvw+RdvnKsN"
    "xNp5RNx/9kqOD+vX9eHqXcgpsQYBVFZQzx/vTx/u207s9hNTPUw83RRVebj+edS/F5XFAhjo"
    "AVCj0NapblTpeWjGkVOm1GRVi7QNMgU4AY0QnKEMw1AgopTzuem7VqrZ9d18/K9FEuZZ5ZwD"
    "5/4H45tv6Xt4MTIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.Append(item)
    return item

class ProgramThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppServerSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()    

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test5"
    _svc_display_name_ = "test5"
    _svc_description_name_ = "test5"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        #wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "exit", event="exit")
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,'Attemping to Start the Service.'))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while True:
            print 1

class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(get_python_logo.GetIcon())

        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

        # create a pubsub receiver
        #pub.subscribe(self.on_exit, "exit")    

        ProgramThread()        

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Site', self.on_hello)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu

    def set_icon(self, path):
        print "set icon"
        icon = wx.Icon(path)
        self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

    def on_hello(self, event):
        print ('Hello, world!')

    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
        self.frame.Close()        

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame)
        return True

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #// Whether called by user or service manager
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        app = App(False)
        app.MainLoop()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: System services execute in session 0, which since Vista (2006) is a reserved session for non-interactive system processes. The first interactive session is session 1. Sessions are an isolating boundary. A process can only access the user interface (i.e. window stations, desktops, windows) of its own session. Windows 10 has user services that execute in interactive sessions, but they're still undocumented. If you just want a program to run at the start of an interactive session, there are multiple ways to accomplish that using the shell or a scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you @ErykSun, makes sense.